# JPA/Hibernate : @PersistenceContext unitName has multiple matches error

Tags: java, jpa, openejb

I am working on a project and so far it went quite well until I have checked out the latest changes from another team, to work on a most up to date files ( do not concentrate on that one ).
I am working using Tomcat OpenEJB 3.1, JPA and Hibernate 3.2.6. What is the problem, after the deployment of application it gets stuck on :

```
2010-10-27 12:31:45,202 - INFO  - Adjusting PersistenceUnit RateQuesto-core <non-jta-data-source> to Resource ID 'jdbc/net.barano.rav.usage.DBNonJta' from 'null'
2010-10-27 12:31:45,202 - INFO  - Configuring PersistenceUnit(name=security_core, provider=org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence)
2010-10-27 12:31:45,202 - INFO  - Adjusting PersistenceUnit security_core <non-jta-data-source> to Resource ID 'jdbc/net.barano.rav.usage.DBNonJta' from 'null'
2010-10-27 12:31:45,233 - ERROR - FAIL ... Rikko.net.barano.rav.c_service.foo.KeyQuesto:    @PersistenceContext unitName has multiple matches: unitName "Rikko" has 16 possible matches.
2010-10-27 12:31:45,233 - ERROR - FAIL ... Rikko.net.barano.rav.c_service.foo.CommonFooQuesto:  @PersistenceContext unitName has multiple matches: unitName "Rikko" has 16 possible matches.
2010-10-27 12:31:45,233 - ERROR - FAIL ... Rikko.net.barano.rav.c_service.foo.internal.CommonFooQueries:    @PersistenceContext unitName has multiple matches: unitName "Rikko" has 16 possible matches.
2010-10-27 12:31:45,233 - ERROR - FAIL ... Rikko.net.barano.rav.c_service.foo.internal.KeyNameQueries:  @PersistenceContext unitName has multiple matches: unitName "Rikko" has 16 possible matches.
2010-10-27 12:31:45,233 - ERROR - FAIL ... Rikko.net.barano.rav.c_service.foo.internal.InternalAttach:  @PersistenceContext unitName has multiple matches: unitName "Rikko" has 16 possible matches.
2010-10-27 12:31:45,233 - ERROR - Invalid EjbModule(path=D:\PR_dev\workspaces v3.2.1\usage 5.4\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\webapps\rav-usage-admin\WEB-INF\lib\rav-cc-Rikkos-core-5.3.003.jar)
2010-10-27 12:31:45,233 - ERROR - FAIL ... security_core.net.barano.rav.c_service.security.authentication.LogonQuesto:  @PersistenceContext unitName has multiple matches: unitName "security_core" has 16 possible matches.
2010-10-27 12:31:45,233 - ERROR - Invalid EjbModule(path=D:\PR_dev\workspaces v3.2.1\usage 5.4\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\webapps\rav-usage-admin\WEB-INF\lib\rav-cc-security-core-5.3.003.jar)
2010-10-27 12:31:45,233 - ERROR - FAIL ... TuruHierarchyQuestoBLBenno:  @PersistenceContext unitName has multiple matches: unitName "rav-usage-core" has 16 possible matches.
```

I have double cheked all the basic settings and none were changed. Did anyone meet with this kind of problems ?

I will appreciate any support in this topic.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd guess that your have your `persistence.xml` 16 times on your classpath. Clean the redundant ones.

Comment: Hi Bozho, thank you for your response, well the classpath doesn't contain it, actually it is totally clear, beacuse I have made another dev server for that purpose and error still occurs.

Comment: this includes all the jars. Did you check them? (If you have some jars of yours in /lib)

Comment: Problem solved, the change came from the checkouted resource. persistance.xml was not excluded in the pom.xml file and all the problems were the consequence of including the persistance.xml in the jar file( the project requirements are that you have to copy that file manually, so for the second time ), thank you for support Bozho.